# разделение файла ejs на несколько частей

Tags: html, ejs

во всех ejs файлах присутствуют элементы и блоки которые не изменяется. как сделать так чтобы прописать эти части в отдельных файлах и подключать их в случае надобности, чтобы каждый раз их не прописывать?

Comment: В ejs есть include, в документации есть раздел об этом https://ejs.co/#docs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В основном файле пишете `<%- include('filepath') %>`. Можно также передать данные:

`<%- include('filepath', {field1: 'one', field2: 'two'}) %>`